# handling large amounts of data using the google maps api

Tags: android

I'm designing an android application where a user can enter there address and it will fetch a list of bars/clubs/eateries within a 300 miles radius.

The way it currently works is, The user inputs his/her address and the app sends a call to a RESTful service(asp) which then selects every bar/club/eaterie and checks there distance from the users location, puts any within a 300 mile distance into an array and returns the result as json once it's finished.

The problem is this is really slow because it has to select every bar/club/eaterie from the database and calculate the distance(I have roughly 20k rows of data)

The average response time for the entire process (user clicking search to having the information displayed on there phone) is about 6-8 seconds, I would like to get it down to about 1-2 seconds

Is there a better way to go about this ? having to select all of the records and check the distance for each one is what's causing the issue.

Comment: Is that your RESTful service or a foreign one?

Comment: Yes-  use a more realistic radius.  Why are you using 300 miles?  Who the heck is going to drive 200 miles for dinner?  Other than that you'd need to show code.  But there's probably optimizations you can do on the distance test check, if you're calculating the actual distance (ways you can replace it with an approximation).

Comment: @t.niese it's my restful service  

 iv'e optimized it as much as possible, The only other thing i can think of doing is storing the data in a sqlLite database and handling it all android sided using the built in location services

Comment: Even 1 second response time is too much if you are on a test system that is not under stress. While it was already mentioned that the search distance might be to large the value is still quite high for only 20k rows of data. So I'm pretty sure the problem is at the place where you gather the data and measure the distance. E.g. Not using a spatial index or something similar.

Comment: The issue is with the google maps api being too slow, I tested it using a maths based approach of longitude/latitude and it took an average of 1.2 seconds which is allot better but using long/lat is incredibly inaccurate as it doesn't take roads into account

Comment: Just brainstorming here, but one way of reducing the amount of data crunching done may be to divide the earth into some size X tiles that you're comfortable with. So you instead query for all the tiles within 300 miles and ask for the establishments related to each tile. Instead of doing a distance calculation on 20000 bars, you do a distance calculation on 20 tiles and return tile.establishments from each.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, Il give it a go

Answer (score 0):

You dont have the GPS location of destinations? If there ale still 20k results in 300miles, you can asynchronously render places in increasing radius. But its true... Why 300 miles?! Another thing is, that I suppose its 300 miles by road, which is nearly impossible to drive and if so, you can load it when user move the map not all at once...

Comment: I tried using longitude and latitude and using a maths based approach towards calculating the difference but it's inaccurate to a degree of about 1:0.70, ie; something 100 miles away on google maps is 70 miles away using longitude and latitude, presumably because long/lat just calculates the distance regardless of if there are roads or not

Comment: yes, but you must just have radius, its impossible count 20k results by distance on road! You are now counting distance by road?